# UI design for Task randomization (online survey tool)

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design, design

Let's say that my tool enables you to create remote usability test (kind of). Users need a new feature - task randomization. 
When user design a project, he/she can add a survey but it isn't obligatory.

[image]

If user chooses 'Task randomization' - ON, he/she should somehow tie up a task with a matching survey to avoid a situation when project flow will look like this:

Welcome page -> Task 3 -> Survey 1 -> Task 2 -> Survey 3 -> Task 1 -> Survey 3 -> End

Do you have any idea how to design such interaction?

Answer (score 3):

I would design the interaction such that each task includes an optional survey that is considered part of the task. That way, randomization will not break the link between task and survey, because they are considered one unit and will always travel together.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to Understand about the product  talk with people then get feedback from people then Google it get inspire from designers make it wireframe  and sketch do prototype then start UI